# Ajax error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax function that allows my site to send a message to me without refreshing the page. But somehow I can't do that because everytime I click it, I get this error in the console:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).

Here is my script:

```
$(function() {

var form = $('#ajax-contact');

var formMessages = $('#form-messages');


$(form).submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = $(form).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData
    }).done(function(response) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
        $(formMessages).addClass('success');

        // Set the message text.
        $(formMessages).text(response);

        // Clear the form.
        $('#name').val('');
        $('#email').val('');
        $('#message').val('');
    }).fail(function(data) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
        $(formMessages).addClass('error');

        // Set the message text.
        if (data.responseText !== '') {
            $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
        } else {
            $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
        }
    });
});


});
```

Here is my PHP file:

```
<?php

// Only process POST reqeusts.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
            $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

    // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
    if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "All fields must be filled.";
        exit;
    }

    // Set the recipient email address.
    // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
    $recipient = "example@example.com";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "New Message from $name";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    // Send the email.
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
    } else {
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Something went wrong.";
    }

} else {
    // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}

?>
```

Comment: Check if the url is correct, if yes then it could be an issue at your server side

Comment: The URL is correct. So what can I do with the issue, I'm pretty new to this, sorry. @NishithChaturvedi

Comment: Telling us you got an internal server error doesn't help much. Look at the server error logs and tell us what the error actually is!

Comment: @Quentin how do I do it? Sorry I'm a so-called 'noob'

Comment: It depends on which HTTP server software you use.

Comment: I use Safari :) @Quentin

Comment: @Snik1 — Safari is a web browser. It is an HTTP **client**. An HTTP server would be something like Apache HTTPD, Microsoft IIS, Lighttpd or Nginx.

Comment: I don't think I have one... I use wordpress, does it have like a default web-server? @Quentin

Comment: Wordpress is a PHP application. PHP is supported by numerous different web servers (including all of the ones I mentioned above).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90311/discussion-between-angelica-and-quentin).

Comment: @Quentin I use MAMP!

Answer (score 0):

First guess

The mail function returns false and you get the Error 500 page.

Try to remove `http_response_code(500);`

If the result doesn't change. Check the **Serverlogs**.

In this case adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the second line could help, depending on your server configuration.

Comment: I tried removing the http_response_code(500); but still it didn't work. So I should put error_reporting(E_ALL); under the http_response_code(500); ?

Answer (score -1):

you need to start debugging by put `die('test')` in every line one by one...

start with die at first line... if u get the die massage in console then remove die from that line and put in next line... follow this debugging step until youy found the php error line.. because i m sure there must be some PHP error in the code.. which give 500 server error...